# Using t-sql how to convert the below example of rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Entity          Description         Units   AssetId
Vehicle 100 A   Distance            8.48     2
Vehicle 100 A   Fuel                11       2
Vehicle 100 A   Parking             9        2
Vehicle 100 A   Tolls               10       2
Vehicle 1       Distance            8.48     5
Vehicle 1       Fuel                8        5
Vehicle 1       Parking             6        5
Vehicle 1       Tolls               7        5
```

Transform above dataset to:

```
Vehicle Description     Distance    Fuel    Parking  Tolls  AssetId
Vehicle 100 A           8.48         11       9       10       2
Vehicle 1               8.48          8       6        7       5
```

Comment: Show what have you tried so far. Look up for `Pivot` in Sql Server

Comment: If `AssetId` has got the same value for each group, you can use `PIVOT`, otherwise look for `pivot conditional aggregat`... Lot's of examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple conditional aggregation may do the trick.

```
Select [Vehicle Description] = Entity          
      ,Distance  = max(case when Description='Distance'  then Units else null end)
      ,Fuel      = max(case when Description='Fuel'      then Units else null end)
      ,Fuel      = max(case when Description='Parking'   then Units else null end)
      ,Tolls     = max(case when Description='Tolls'     then Units else null end)
      ,AssetId   = max(AssetID)
  From YourTable
  Group By Entity
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the PIVOT syntax you can do it this way:

```
SELECT Entity [Vehicle Description],
   Distance,
   Fuel,
   Parking,
   Tolls,
   AssetId
FROM
(
SELECT Entity,
       Description,
       Units,
       Assetid
FROM yourtable) pt 
PIVOT(SUM(units) FOR description 
IN(Distance, Fuel, Parking, Tolls)) piv;
```